# How to get access to a directory and its files from tree URI path with SAF

Tags: android, android-10.0, storage-access-framework, android-storage, android-11

I want to pick all files in a directory and then store as copy compressed version of these files in the same directory.

If I use `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` I get a tree `Uri`, but I cannot figure how I could get the file Uri of all files contained in it and how to write in the directory itself.

In the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files) I cannot find any similar use case.

Before forced *SAF* it was enough to get directory path and work with standard File methods, unfortunately now all the past methods based on Files and explicit paths are broken with this SAF.

Comment: It is possible to list all the files too using the uri obtained with the mentioned action. If you google a bit you will find exampled.

Comment: Something like DocumentFile docFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(uri);  DocumentFile files[] = docFile.listFiles();.

Answer (score 3):

It tooks me a while to figure out:

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private List<Uri> readFiles(Context context, Intent intent) {
    List<Uri> uriList = new ArrayList<>();

    // the uri returned by Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE
    Uri uriTree = intent.getData();
    // the uri from which we query the files
    Uri uriFolder = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(uriTree, DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(uriTree));

    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        // let's query the files
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uriFolder,
                new String[]{DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID},
                null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                // build the uri for the file
                Uri uriFile = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(uriTree, cursor.getString(0));
                //add to the list
                uriList.add(uriFile);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle error
    } finally {
        if (cursor!=null) cursor.close();
    }

    //return the list
    return uriList;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot figure how I could get the file Uri of all files contained in it and how to write in the directory itself.

Use `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` to get a `DocumentFile` from the `Uri` that you get back from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`. You can then use methods on `DocumentFile` to list the "files" in the "directory", plus `createFile()` to create a new document ("file") in the tree.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm trying to following your suggestion, using such cumbersome SAF `DocumentFile`implementation I was able to get  Uri for read operations, but I have problem with file creation. Could you add more details or a small code snippet to show me how to properly write the file? (However I still think that SAF definition that you have edited in my post was appropriate for this monstrosity :P )

Comment: @AndreaF: "Could you add more details" -- there is [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/11/09/scoped-storage-stories-trees.html) and other posts in that series. "I still think that SAF definition that you have edited in my post was appropriate for this monstrosity" -- oh, I won't argue that point. I just don't think that it was really appropriate for a Stack Overflow question and might have caused your question to get closed/deleted at some point.

Comment: @AndreaF: In [this sample Kotlin app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v0.9/ContentEditor) and [its Java equivalent](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v0.9/ContentEditor), I write content to a document via a `Uri`. In my case, though, that `Uri` was not set up via a tree, but via single-document SAF operations (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`).

Comment: Following your sample, I was able to write text file correctly, but if I try to write a generic serializable object rather than text, using `ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(os)); out.writeObject(someserializableobject);` rather than `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));` it doesn\t write anything in the created file

Comment: @AndreaF: Personally, I would never use serializable objects. Regardless, how are you determining that nothing is being written out? Are you using Device File Explorer in Android Studio, or perhaps `adb shell ls`?

Comment: I have checked with file explorer and file is empty with size 0 when I try to write Serializable. I need Serializable because I have to write a file derived by a complex structured Object, the alternative (create some parser with encoded xml or similar) would be much slower and inefficient adding lots of overhead and complications

Comment: @AndreaF: "would be much slower and inefficient" -- I doubt that. Some options might even be faster (e.g., saving a `byte[]` from protobuf/Wire). 25-year-old largely-unused file formats are unlikely to age well, IMHO. Make sure that you `flush()` your `ObjectOutputStream`. Also, you could try creating the `ObjectOutputStream` to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, then persist the resulting `byte[]`. Otherwise, you could ask another SO question, with a [mcve] showing what you are trying.

Comment: Serializable can be easily implemented on all kind of Objects without complex parsing procedures, not sure if the same applies to Wire, I'll do some research, however here the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62362953/attempt-to-write-serializable-object-with-saf-gives-as-result-an-empty-file

Comment: @CommonsWare how can we make this permission to read files in folder permanent, like I don't want to ask user this permission every time he opens the app. It has to be like ones he gives the permission it has to permanent. I want to access .jpg & .mp4 files from "/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses" folder

Comment: @mad_lad: Call `takePersistableUriPermission()` on a `ContentResolver`, passing in the `Uri` that you get from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.

Comment: What code to use on DocumentFile that list all files in the treeUri