# Attempt to write Serializable Object with SAF gives as result an empty file

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I want to use SAF to write Object files

To write a text files If I try:

```
    DocumentFile txtfile=df.createFile("text", "myfile.txt");
    Uri source = txtfile.getUri();
    resolver = getContentResolver();
    OutputStream os = resolver.openOutputStream(source);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
    out.print(somestring);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```

the file is correctly created and written.

But if I try in a similar way to write a `Serializable` object rather than a string with this code:

```
    DocumentFile serialfile=df.createFile("unspecified", "myserializable");
    Uri source = serialfile.getUri();        
    resolver = getContentResolver();
    OutputStream os = resolver.openOutputStream(source);
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(os));
    out.writeObject(someserializable);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```

The file is created correctly, but it's totally empty regardless the fact the `Serializable` object is valid for sure (If I try to write it with traditional `FileOutputStream` methods, rather than SAF procedure above, it's written correctly)